# Eclipse external builder export/save configuration?

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

So if you right click on your project and go properties, under Builders I add the android ndk builder to the project so it will compile the jni stuff when I run my app that im working on.

Is there a way to save the builder configuration so that you can easily add it to other projects? At the moment I have to remake the build configuration every time I add/make a new project (when im trying to add demo/sample projects to look at). Its not the end of the world its just annoying and there should be a way to save the configuration between projects, but I just cant find where.